# proper way to round values in pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, rounding

There are many topics decribing python 3 problems with rounding, and how to solve it to single value, but I couldn't find how to round values in pandas dataframe.

```
input:
  A,B
  1.5,2
  1.2,3
  2.5,1

df['A']=df['A'].astype(float).round(decimals=0)
output in python 2:
 A,B
  2,2
  1,3
  3,1
output in python 3:

 A,B
  1,2
  1,3
  2,1
```

How to achieve result from python 2 in python 3 for pandas columns?

I have tried to convert it to decimals but it doesnt work for pandas.

my workaround for this would be:

```
df['A']=np.floor(df['A'].astype(float)+0.5)
```

any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `numpy.around` to round off your dataframe in python3.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.around.html

here is an example

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df = pd.DataFrame([[1.5,2],[1.2,3]])
    print(df)
    >>>      0  1
       0   1.5  2
       1   1.2  3
    df = np.around(df)
    print(df)
    >>>      0  1
       0   2.0  2
       1   1.0  3
```

Comment: hi, you created list not dataframe, but anyway try it with for example value == 46.5, it does not work

Comment: ok, you are misunderstanding here. 46.5 == 46 is not wrong,  _6.5 rounds down to  _6 ( because 6 is an even number).  check this link https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/rounding-methods.html

Comment: but normally should be 47, thats the topic of this thread, in python 2.7 where was no problems with such kind of things, my dataset have over milion rows, and i need working solution

Answer (score 0):

best way to do that for me in python 3 will be :

`df['A']=np.floor(df['A'].astype(float)+0.5)`

I dont see better way at this moment

Regards